# What does the ouput of StructureDescription mean in GAP?

Tags: gap

`gap> StructureDescription(G);`

Gives: `"(C5 x C5) : C12"`

How exactly should this output be interpreted?

Comment: It is a non-trivial semi-direct product of $(\mathbb Z/5)^2$ with $\mathbb Z/12$.

Comment: This is explained in the manual entry for StructureDescription, see https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap39_mj.html#X8199B74B84446971